# Kafka Producer in AIX 7.1 crontab getting a JAVA error: Bad Major Version

Tags: java, cron, apache-kafka, aix, kafka-producer-api

I'm having a bit of difficulties drilling down on this error, and can't seem to find anything related to this issue with my setup. I did find some articles out there regarding the error in general but after research they are not applicable to my setup.

Here's what's going on... and I only pointed out that it's happening on IBM AIX 7.1 in case there's anything specific to AIX I should look at, but I would imagine this error could also happen on Linux machines as well.

The goal:

Run a command, pipe the command to kafka-console-producer.sh to a specific Kafka topic, as such:

```
    ps -ef | /kafka/bin/kafka-console-producer.sh --broker-list <IP>:9092 --topic running_processes
```

The command above takes the output of "ps -ef" and sends it off to my topic (running_processes). **This works perfectly fine with no issues if I run it while logged into the system via the shell.**

However, if I do the exact same thing as script in a crontab entry that runs every 5 minutes, like this:

```
    0,5,10,15,20,25,30,35,40,45,50,55 <path of script> >> <path of log> 2>&1
```

This is what I get in my log file:

```
    ...
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: JVMCFRE003 bad major version; class=org/apache/kafka/clients/producer/Callback, offset=6
    ...
```

My first guess was that the JAVA_HOME environment variable wasn't set for the context of crontab, so I manually added that environment variable in the script to make sure JAVA_HOME is saved.

Also, I looked at the kafka/bin/kafka-run-class.sh file and looked at other possible variables that come into play, since after all the kafka-console-producer.sh does reference that file. For example, I manually set the JAVA_MAJOR_VERSION referenced in that file as part of the script as well.

Still no luck. Again, what is racking my brain here is that as a normal user logged into the shell, if I run the script, it works. It only doesn't work when using crontab to schedule the script at an interval.

Everything is pointing me to some environment variable not available within the context of crontab, but I can't figure it out.

Any ideas?

Comment: After setting `JAVA_HOME` set `PATH` too: `export PATH="$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH"`

Answer (score 1):

As @LorinczyZsigmond stated, after setting JAVA_HOME, and then path (export PATH="$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH" worked. Thank you!